# Apache: Where are 421 errors logged?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a very strange problem with 421 errors, but I cannot debug it because I cannot locate the logs. It is not in the ErrorLog file which is defined in the httpd.conf file and also not in the CustomLog file which is defined in the vhost file.

How can logging for 421 errors be turned on and is it possible to get strings of the mismatching "requested host name" and "Server Name Identification" ?

Answer (score 1):

The `CustomLog` file defined for your `VirtualHost` is only used when the request actually matches that `VirtualHost` specification.

There should be another `CustomLog` or `AccessLog` definition with global scope somewhere in your configuration (which you didn't share) and this would be where requests which don't match any `VirtualHost` would be logged.

Comment: Well it does also not appear in the central CustomLog in the global httpd.conf file

Comment: And what about server's ErrorLog, or default vitualhost logs?

Comment: I only define ErrorLog globally (not in vhosts) and it is not there

Comment: CustomLog is defined for each vhost and I cannot find it there and also not in the global CustomLog.

Comment: Do you think it is worth the try to also add AccessLog? Is there a difference to CustomLog?

Comment: If it doesn't appear in any Apache logs then I'd suspect it doesn't even reach the Apache server. Do you have `iptables` configured on the host? If so, activate logging for incoming connections to the Apache service to make sure the connections in question are really answered by your Apache process and not by some intervening network instance. If not, check the logs of your network firewall for same.